# Accidentally deleted project configuring github on eclipse. How do i get it back?

Tags: eclipse, git

I "committed" my java project -or tried to. I only just downloaded egit for eclipse and was trying to configure it. I realized my project had not been uploaded so tried to delete what i did to start again.

I thought I was just deleting the commit but it deleted the whole project locally! It's not in my trash either.

Anyone any idea how to get it back?

Comment: Well, is any version of it stored on github, or didn't you get that far?

Comment: get something that recovers from hard disk, if you are lucky it will work

Comment: I didn't get that far... :-( also. How has it not gone into the trash at least! I thought git was all about version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you didn't push the file to the remote repo and you deleted the entire project, then you have lost your local git repo. Check your recycle bin, or try to do a hard drive recovery, if you are lucky. Otherwise...**S.O.L.** Sorry :-(

Comment: Worked out quicker to redo than to try and save from hard drive! I think I get how to not repeat that mistake again now...